# ¿como desplegar correctamente una app angular con bootstrap para heroku?

Tags: bootstrap-4, heroku, deployment, angular5

estuve siguiendo este [tutorial](https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147.):

pero heroku log me arrojo estos **errores**:

> Node.js app detected  Creating runtime environment
>          NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>          NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
>          NODE_VERBOSE=false
>          NODE_ENV=production
>          NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true  Installing binaries
>          engines.node (package.json):  8.9.3
>          engines.npm (package.json):   5.5.1
>          Resolving node version 8.9.3...
>          Downloading and installing node 8.9.3...
>          npm 5.5.1 already installed with node  Restoring cache
>          Skipping cache restore (new-signature)  Building dependencies
>          Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
>
> ```
>     node-sass@4.7.2 install /tmp/build_584ae7eac91cbd7246b437f815629c94/WaverNoiser-beatsapp-1b1fccd/node_modules/node-sass
>     node scripts/install.js
>    Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/linux-x64-57_binding.node
>    Download complete
>    Binary saved to /tmp/build_584ae7eac91cbd7246b437f815629c94/WaverNoiser-beatsapp-1b1fccd/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
>    Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.PV9Nf/node-sass/4.7.2/linux-x64-57_binding.node
>    uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_584ae7eac91cbd7246b437f815629c94/WaverNoiser-beatsapp-1b1fccd/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
>   node lib/post_install.js
>     node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall /tmp/build_584ae7eac91cbd7246b437f815629c94/WaverNoiser-beatsapp-1b1fccd/node_modules/node-sass
>   > node scripts/build.js
>    Binary found at /tmp/build_584ae7eac91cbd7246b437f815629c94/WaverNoiser-beatsapp-1b1fccd/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
>    Testing binary
>    Binary is fine
>     beats-app@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_584ae7eac91cbd7246b437f815629c94/WaverNoiser-beatsapp-1b1fccd
>     ng build --aot -prod
>    Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
>    The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.
>    Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
>    devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
>    run npm install again.
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>    npm ERR! errno 2
>    npm ERR! beats-app@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --aot -prod`
>    npm ERR! Exit status 2
>    npm ERR!
>    npm ERR! Failed at the beats-app@0.0.0 postinstall script.
>    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>    npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.PV9Nf/_logs/2018-02-26T15_17_22_489Z-debug.log
> ```
>
> Build failed
>          We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
>          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
>          If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
>          https://help.heroku.com/
>          Love,
>          Heroku  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  !     Push failed

Después intente hacer npm install localmente y medio estos **errores**:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Module
>   build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
>       at error (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
>       at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
>       at Function.select (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
>       at C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at browserslist (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
>       at C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\dist\index.js:261:51
>       at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:277:20)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:192:32)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>   @ multi ./src/styles.css
>   ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Module build
>   failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: BrowserslistError:
>   Unknown browser major
>       at error (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
>       at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
>       at Function.select (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
>       at C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at browserslist (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
>       at C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\dist\index.js:261:51
>       at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:277:20)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:192:32)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
>       at runLoaders (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:195:19)
>       at C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>       at C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>       at context.callback (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>       at Promise.resolve.then.then.catch (C:\Users\noiser\Documents\Angular\MusicApp_V1\public\BeatsApp\node_modules\postcss-loader\lib\index.js:197:71)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)  @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css  @ multi
>   ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

si ejecuto ng serve la app se ejecuta de manera correcta pero no logro ejecutarla desde heroku, sospecho que tiene que ver con las dependencias de bootstrap pero no tengo idea de como resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

tuviste en cuenta importar el archivo css de boostrap mediante el archivo de configuración de angular ***angular.cli.json***

`"apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
    }
  ],`

Comment: si, esta agregado .